# Copying files using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, caddyfile, stoplight

I am new to Docker Compose, and I was trying modify an example on [serving multiple OpenAPI documents using Stoplight Prism](https://docs.stoplight.io/docs/prism/4bf78efbf9dd2-serving-multiple-open-api-documents). I have the file I want to copy under the directory `/reference/Offers/Offers-APIs.v1.json`, and in the project's root directory, I have a `Dockerfile` that copies the entire repository under `/app`. My question is, how to copy `Offers-APIs.v1.json` such that it is accessible in my `docker-compose.yaml` file?

My current attempt is this:

```
  prism_1:
    image: stoplight/prism:5  
      - ./reference/:/app/
    command: >
      mock -p 4010 --host 0.0.0.0 -d app/reference/Offers/Offers-APIs.v1.json
```

where the last line is a `prism mock` command that mocks my API. I attempt to copy the entire `reference` folder to `/app` directory, but when I run the program, it displays this error:

```
[7:07:46 PM] › [CLI] ✖  fatal     Error opening file "/usr/src/prism/packages/cli/app/reference/Offers/Offers-APIs.v1.json" 
2023-07-24T19:07:46.049079100Z ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/prism/packages/cli/app/reference/Offers/Offers-APIs.v1.json'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the getting started docs you should be able to start prism5 with these docker-compose file (I tried and it worked):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  prism_1:
    image: stoplight/prism:5
    volumes:
      - ./Offers.yml:/tmp/Offers.yml:ro
    command: 'mock -p 4010 --host 0.0.0.0 -d /tmp/Offers.yml'
    ports:
      - '8080:4010'
```

In my Offers.yml file i added the content of:

https://github.com/stoplightio/prism/blob/master/examples/petstore.oas2.yaml

You could try using your json file instead.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't help. It's still giving the same error. I realized if I add an extra `/` in front of `app`, it's giving a different error: `Error opening file "/app/reference/Offers/Offers-APIs.v1.json"`, so it's no longer coming from `/usr/src...` directory if that's a valid information.